# Multiple tables into one lookup field

Tags: ms-access-2010, lookup

I have multiple tables that have different machine lists based on different criteria. I'm trying to create one master table to use as a contact list, so I can document which machine owners I've contacted.

Here's a basic list of tables:

Table 1

IP Address | Asset Name | Contact

Table 2

Asset Name | Contact

Table 3

IP Address | Contact

In another table, is it possible to have one field that includes the Contact value from the 3 tables into one? So the table would have the following columns:

IP Address | Asset Name | Merged Contacts Field

Thanks.

Comment: I have already created a table that lists the separate fields side by side but it looks weird.

Comment: Forget all about lookup fields and create queries. If you are not familiar with these, look up a guide as the first thing you do. Lookup fields is a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just using several nested IFERROR VLOOKUPS in Excel for what I needed to do in Access.

I'm sure there's a way to do it in Access, so that'll be my next step.